# Removing XML elements based on attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I couldn't find a solution for my problem here, So please help me to find a way to filter elements of XML document based on value of attributes.

Clearly, for a document like this:

```
<records>
    <record>
        <Rec1>Guy Levy</Rec1>
        <Rec2 Type="1">72910589</Rec2>
        <Rec3 Type="2">some content</Rec3>
        <Rec4 Type="3">some content</Rec4>
        <Rec5 Type="4">some content</Rec5>
        <Rec6 Type="5">some content</Rec6>
        <Rec7 Type="6">some content</Rec7>
    </record>
    <record>
        <Rec1>Bruno Vang</Rec1>
        <Rec2 Type="1">some content</Rec2>
        <Rec3 Type="2">some content</Rec3>
        <Rec4 Type="3">some content</Rec4>
        <Rec5 Type="4">some content</Rec5>
        <Rec6 Type="5">some content</Rec6>
        <Rec7 Type="6">some content</Rec7>
    </record>
</records>
```

I want to have elements with , for example, attributes Type="1" and Type="3":

```
<records>
        <record>
            <Rec1>Guy Levy</Rec1>
            <Rec2 Type="1">72910589</Rec2>
            <Rec4 Type="3">some content</Rec4>
        </record>
        <record>
            <Rec1>Bruno Vang</Rec1>
            <Rec2 Type="1">some content</Rec2>
            <Rec4 Type="3">some content</Rec4>
        </record>
    </records>
```

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**
For records that some or all elements have not attributes, the provided solution would not be practical. For example, the below fragment

```
<record>
    <Rec1>Guy Levy</Rec1>
    <Rec2 Type="1">72910589</Rec2>
    <Rec3>some content</Rec3>
    <Rec4 Type="3">some content</Rec4>
    <Rec5>some content</Rec5>
    <Rec6>some content</Rec6>
    <Rec7 Type="6">some content</Rec7>
</record>
```

Comment: What is the desired output for your new example?

Comment: So where is the logic that says that the "Guy Levy" element should stay, but the "some content" elements should be removed? You haven't explained that.

Comment: You're right. I should explain that the first element should remain and others filter based on the attributes value. Of course, the problem could be stated in another form that is closer to my goal: Only elements that match the query (desired attributes' values) should remain and others sould be removed, even first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple identity transform with a template to match the items to remove will do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record/*[not(position() = 1 or
                                    @Type = '1' or 
                                    @Type = '3')]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<records>
  <record>
    <Rec1>Guy Levy</Rec1>
    <Rec2 Type="1">72910589</Rec2>
    <Rec4 Type="3">some content</Rec4>
  </record>
  <record>
    <Rec1>Bruno Vang</Rec1>
    <Rec2 Type="1">some content</Rec2>
    <Rec4 Type="3">some content</Rec4>
  </record>
</records>
```